# Upload photo to facebook from app

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

How to upload photo to facebook wall from within an app ? I have seen lot of examples but they only give the call function for url. I have downloaded facebook framework but i am not sure how it works . I have seen sample codes from this framework but how to call the method to post the image to Facebook? Does anyone have complete code to upload the photo to FB ?

```
    -(void)postUserInformation:(id)sender
  {

    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house2.jpg"];

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"Testing Feed Dialog", @"name",
     @"Feed Dialogs are Awesome.", @"caption",
     @"Check out how to use Facebook Dialogs.", @"description",
     @"http://www.example.com/", @"link",
     data, @"picture",
     nil];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: compose view http://www.developers-life.com/facebook-compose-view.html

Comment: Add your code here so we can help you troubleshoot your code.

Answer (score 2):

Hello please check out the below example of facebook in which you can find out how to share image on facebook [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebookdemo/files/FacebookDemo.zip/download)

just check the example in which you found the class HomeViewController in which find method `-(void)postUserInformation:(id)sender` the commented method will post local image and the running code will share server image.

let me know if you have any query

Comment: I downloaded that code but nothing happens. Picture is not posted to the wall on my facebook page . Where to call that method?

Comment: have you run the project? get the first screen with a single button?

Comment: Yup i got it. When pressed i got one window about the login infer. Then i got two buttons with user and image and my profile pic. Then i selected image. Then nothing happens. I cannot see the uploaded photo to my wall.

Comment: when you pressed image what you get ? any dialog box open with image ?

Comment: Yes. I got the image in my facebook wall. But how to select image which is added in the NSBundle or document directory? Do i have to give the path to the value of the key "picture" ?

Comment: simple convert image into NSData and passed this data into @"picture" key. see the commented code in the postUserInformation method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16602/discussion-between-cocoa-matters-and-prerna-chavan)

Comment: Please help me my application is crashing if i convert image to data.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code for posting image.

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage)];

Answer (score 1):

you can find information on that here

[Facebook upload photo](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)